# How to fix these invalid types of arguments (linked-lists/structs) and make sure they don't happen again?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

So, this semester in college we started learning C. I thought I grasped the concept of pointers but now I realize I really need your help. As a final assignement, we need to write a program that, amongst other things, is able to read a set of words from a file, put them all in a linked list, and sort it (alphabetically and by another criteria). I'm currently trying to code this part, but am facing a lot of "invalid type argument ->" and such, so I really need help understanding what I'm doing wrong, how to fix it, and how to make sure it doesn't happen again due to my ignorance.

```
typedef struct local{
    char *name;
    struct local *next;

}t_local;

void printlocalsalphabetical(t_local *header_l){
    createlistlocals(*header_l);
    sort_alphabetical(*header_l);

    t_local l   = header_l->next;
    while (l){
        puts(l->name);
        l=l->next;
    }

}

void crialistlocals(t_local *header_l){
    FILE *fp;
    t_local *aux = header_l->next;
    char line[150];
    char *namel;
    fp = fopen("locais.txt","r");

    while (!feof(fp)){
        fgets(line, 100, fp);
        namel = strtok(line, '/');
        aux->name = namel;
        aux->next = header_l;
        header_l= aux;
    }

}

void sort_alphabetical(t_local *header_l){
    int swapped;
    t_local *ptr1;
    t_local *lptr = NULL;


    if (header_l == NULL)
        return;

    do
    {
        swapped = 0;
        ptr1 = header_l;

        while (ptr1->next != lptr)
        {
            if (ptr1->name > ptr1->prox->name)
            {
                swap(ptr1, ptr1->next);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            ptr1 = ptr1->next;
        }
        lptr = ptr1;
    }
    while (swapped);
}

void swap(t_local *a, t_local *b)
{
    char *temp = a->name;
    a->name = b->name;
    b->name = strdup(temp);
}


t_local *create_headerL(void){
    t_local *list = (t_local*)malloc(sizeof(t_local));
    if (list != NULL)
        list->next = NULL;

    return lista;

}

int main()
{
    t_local *header_l = create_headerL();
    printlocalsalphabetical(*header_l);
    return 0;

}
```

I'm really struggling with this and I'm starting to really freak out due to my inability to understand it, so all and any help is very very welcome

Answer (score 1):

You must know when to use a pointer and when not. (If you work with linked lists, you will usually need pointers.) You also must know when an asterisk defines a pointer and when it dereferences it.

```
void printlocalsalphabetical(t_local *header_l)
```

This is the definition. `header_l` is a pointer to `t_local`.

```
    createlistlocals(*header_l);
    sort_alphabetical(*header_l);
```

These are function calls, where the `*header_l`'s  are expressions that dereference the pointer, giving a `t_local`. Both functions want a pointer to `t_local`, so remove the asterisk.

```
    t_local l = header_l->next;
```

Here, you define a `t_local`, but `header_l->next` is a pointer to `t_local`, and `l` should also be a pointer: Change to `t_local *l`.

```
        puts(l->name);
        l=l->next;
```

The `->` operator works only if the left hand side is a pointer to a struct or sunion. Using `.` will fix the syntax error, but it will not fi the code. In fact, the code was already fixed by changing the type of `l` to `t_local *`.

(I've only looked at the first function here, but I hope you get the idea.)

So there's no need to freak out. Keep a calm head, read the error messages, determine whether you want a pointer or not, then repair yor code. The error messages are there to help you, not to annoy you.